# How to use `otherwise` in ui-router of angular 2?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular, angular-ui-router

In ui-router we can add `otherwise` to handle invalid/unregistered state. Here's in AngularJS

```
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/index');
```

Meaning, that every invalid URL will go to `'/index'` eventually. How do we do the same thing in ui-router for Angular 2? I've already used `UIRouterModule.forRoot()` and `UIRouterModule.forChild()` in `imports` of `app.module.ts`.

```
UIRouterModule.forRoot({ states: [loginState] }),
UIRouterModule.forChild({ states: [homeState] })
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [`UIRouterModule.forRoot` docs](https://ui-router.github.io/docs/latest/classes/ng2.uiroutermodule.html#forroot) show an example of how to use the `otherwise` property:

```
UIRouterModule.forRoot({ states: [loginState], otherwise: '/index' }),
UIRouterModule.forChild({ states: [homeState] })
```

Comment: this is it! Thanks for your help!

Answer (score -1):

You actually use $urlRouterProvider in conjunction with $stateProvider

So, first you will need to define your state with $stateProvider

```
 $stateProvider
    .state("otherwise", { url : '/index'...})
```

and then set .otherwise on $urlRouterProvider to the url from the state we defined first

```
$urlRouterProvider
        .otherwise('/index');
```